# Android How to stream Hikvision IP Camera with 2way audio communication

Tags: android, rtsp, ip-camera, isapi, hikvision

I am looking for the code to live stream Hikvision cameras in Android App using RTSP stream to play video properly.
However unable to find the 2-way Audio communication functionality just like [IVMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mcu.iVMS&hl=en) Official App.

What protocol should be the to be used for same. I tried Hikvision IP Camera APIs but no use.

```
/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/ID
General Resource v2.0
GET
Description It is used to get a particular two way audio channel
Query None
Inbound Data None
Success Return TwoWayAudioChannel


/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/ID/open General Resource
v2.0
PUT
Description It is used to open the two way audio channel.
Query None
Inbound Data None
Success Return TwoWayAudioSession
```

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this out. My blog post on it is [here](https://blog.speedfox.co.uk/articles/1666958513-ip_camera_intercom/) and the source code for the android app I wrote to do it is [here](https://github.com/speedfox-uk/IpCameraIntercom). You'll need to take a look at the ISAPI documentation to understand the code ([here](https://github.com/loozhengyuan/hikvision-sdk/blob/master/resources/isapi.pdf)) but in short, the TwoWayAudio functionality does not use RTSP. Rather when you make the audioData calls to send and receive audio you need to make sure the TCP/IP connection underlying the HTTP call stays open, and then you just send/receive raw bytes over that.
Just a warning on the code for the android app: There is a lot of stuff in there hardcoded for my own setup , so might require a bit of modification to get it working in another setup.

Answer (score 0):

this is the isapi url you need to use
#define HTTP_TWOWAY_AUDIO_OPEN_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/open"
#define HTTP_TWOWAY_AUDIO_CLOSE_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/close"
#define HTTP_GET_TWOWAY_AUDIO_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/audioData"